# CSS - Fade In Opacity Animation - Element shows then does animation

Tags: css, css-animations, opacity

I have a fade in animation with an opacity, its working great except the fact is the element is showing when the page is loading, then does the animation...

Here is my **CSS** code:

```
.header-wrap {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

And here are the `keyframes`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -o-transform: translatex(-10px);
        transform: translatex(-10px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0);
        -o-transform: translatex(0);
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -o-transform: translatex(-10px);
        transform: translatex(-10px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0);
        -o-transform: translatex(0);
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(-100px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(-100px);
        -o-transform: translatex(-100px);
        transform: translatex(-100px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0);
        -o-transform: translatex(0);
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
}
```

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

I have also tried setting the opacity to 0 in my element, but all that does is not show the element after the animation.

```
.header-wrap {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution i came to

the header-wrap

```
.header-wrap {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
-moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
-o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
animation-name: fadeInLeft;

webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;   
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;     
-ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;    
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-o-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1s;
-o-animation-duration:1s;
animation-delay: 1s;

-webkit-transform: translatex(-100px);
-moz-transform: translatex(-100px);
-o-transform: translatex(-100px);
transform: translatex(-100px);
}
```

the key frames

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
from {
    opacity:0;

}
to {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: translatex(0px);
    -moz-transform: translatex(0px);
    -o-transform: translatex(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);

    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;

    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0px);
        -o-transform: translatex(0px);
        transform: translatex(0px);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;

    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0px);
        -o-transform: translatex(0px);
        transform: translatex(0px);

    }
}
```

by translating prior to your keyframes methods and setting opactity to 0 in the header-wrap and using fill mode forward it should work, its working for me on chrome

Answer (score 0):

You should set animation-fill-mode of header-wrap to forward so the opacity stays on 1 after the animation

.header-wrap should look like this

```
.header-wrap {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I just edited my post, maybe this works for you

Comment: Now it doesnt appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

add `opacity:0` to your header so it won't show up on load! then add `animation-fill-mode:forwards` to apply the lasts properties in your animation to your header

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -o-transform: translatex(-10px);
        transform: translatex(-10px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0);
        -o-transform: translatex(0);
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(-10px);
        -o-transform: translatex(-10px);
        transform: translatex(-10px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0);
        -o-transform: translatex(0);
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInLeft {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(-100px);
        -moz-transform: translatex(-100px);
        -o-transform: translatex(-100px);
        transform: translatex(-100px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform: translatex(0);
        -moz-transform: translatex(0);
        -o-transform: translatex(0);
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
}
.header-wrap {
  opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header-wrap">header</h1>
```